# Multivariable monotonic function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ be a real function on the $n$-dimensional unit cube (that is, mapping $[0,1]^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$). Assume furthermore that $f$ is monotonic in every coordinate, and that $f$ is bounded.

I have the following questions:

1. Is it clear that $f$ is measurable (with respect to Borel sets on $[0,1]^n$)?
2. Is it true that there exists a function $\hat{f}$ which is right-continous (at every point, in every coordinate) such that $f=\hat{f}$ except on a set of Lebesgue measure zero?

If you know the answer, please also provide a reference (if possible).

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: No, it is not. If it seems so trivial for you, then please tell me the solution.

Comment: It doesn't seem trivial to me (although I know barely any analysis :P); I was only worried because there is no clear motivation given, and this form of question is common in real analysis courses.

Comment: The motivation is that I am proving something about the integral of bounded, monotonic (multivariate) functions. And the question is, if I know that the function is bounded and monotonic, is it then clear that it is also integrable, or do I also have to assume that it is measurable.

Comment: While there are functions monotonic which are not Borel measurable, every function which is monotonic in all variables is Lebesgue measurable. See this question. http://mathoverflow.net/q/134304/22277

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f$ need not be Borel measurable: Let $f(x,y)=0$ on $x+y<1$ and $f=1$ on $x+y>1$, and on the diagonal $x+y=1$, set $f=1/2$ for $x\in E$ and $f=0$ otherwise, where $E\subset [0,1]$ is not Borel. Then $f^{-1}(\{ 1/2 \})$ is not a Borel set in the square.

Answer (score 1):

As for the second question, let $\hat f(x):=\inf_{y>x}f(y)$ on $[0,1)^n$, where $y>x$ means that $y_i>x_i$ for all $i$. One has $\hat f\ge f$ and it is easy to check that $\hat f$ is increasing and right-continuous in every variable.

Also, if you fix $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $v:=(1,\dots,1)$, then $s\mapsto\hat f(x+sv)$ is bounded above by the right-continuous representative of the increasing function $s\mapsto f(x+sv)$, which is just $s\mapsto\inf_{t>s}f(x+sv)$. Since the two agree for a.e. $t$ (as in one dimension an increasing function has at most countably many "jumps"), Fubini's theorem implies $f=\hat f$ a.e.

Comment: I just realized that this question was posted 6 years ago. I have no clue why it appeared on the homepage.

Comment: No worries. Thanks all the same.